# Nested Child objects are not reactive in Vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have JSON data like the one below-

```
items: {
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    id: 2,
    parentId: 1,
    children: [{
      id: 3,
      parentId: 2
    }]
  }]
}
```

`level-1` children are parent items that all have parent_id, 1 (root node's id) and `level-2` children are child items that have parent_id of respective `level-1` child's id

From this data, I am creating a tree-view UI using Vuetify where each parent and child item of the tree is editable. See the UI for reference-

[image]

**Problem-**

The parent items are updating fine but not the child items. Especially this scenario is problematic-

1. Update any child first (working)
2. Then update its parent (working)
3. Again update the child (not working)

**Update logic-**

I find the item's indexes by their ids and update the item at that index using `Vue.set`. I can see that data is updating in the array but not updating in the template.

Here is the demo. If the logic is complex please suggest another way but I can only think about this approach.

```js
Vue.component('my-dialog', {
  template: `<v-dialog :value="dialog" persistent><v-card><v-text-field v-model="form.title"></v-text-field></v-card><v-btn @click="$emit('on-update', form)">Save</v-btn></v-dialog>`,
  props: {
    dialog: {},
    prop_item: {}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        title: null
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    Object.assign(this.form, this.prop_item);
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      edit_item: {},
      items: {"id":1,"title":"Root","children":[{"id":2,"parentId":1,"title":"Chapter 1","children":[{"id":3,"parentId":2,"title":"Sub-chapter 1.1"},{"id":4,"parentId":2,"title":"Sub-chapter 1.2"}]},{"id":5,"parentId":1,"title":"Chapter 2","children":[{"id":6,"parentId":5,"title":"Sub-chapter 2.1"},{"id":7,"parentId":5,"title":"Sub-chapter 2.2"}]}]}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showDialog(payload) {
      this.edit_item = payload;
      this.dialog = true;
    },
    onUpdate(payload) {
      this.dialog = false;
      // Extract the parent id
      let parent_id = payload.parentId == 1 ? payload.id : payload.parentId;
      let index = this.items.children.findIndex((item) => item.id == parent_id);
      if (index == -1) return;
      // If parent is requested to update
      if (payload.parentId == 1) {
        Vue.set(this.items.children, index, payload);
        return;
      }
      // If child is requested to update
      let childIndex = this.items.children[index].children.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id == payload.id,
      );
      if (childIndex != -1) {
        Vue.set(this.items.children[index].children, childIndex, payload);
        console.log(this.items.children[index].children[childIndex])
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <my-dialog v-if="dialog" v-model="dialog" :dialog="dialog" :prop_item="edit_item" @on-update="onUpdate"></my-dialog>
      <v-treeview :items="items.children" item-text="title">
        <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
          <v-icon @click.stop="showDialog(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-treeview>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the dialog only update the specific item's title and nothing else?

Comment: Yes, only the title. And the title is updated in the array but not reflected in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the process by using `Vue.set` and passing/handling the updated fields in the dialog's event.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <my-dialog :dialog="dialog" :prop_item="edit_item" @on-update="onUpdate"></my-dialog>

      <v-treeview :items="items.children" item-text="title">
        <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
          <v-icon @click.stop="showDialog(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-treeview>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
Vue.component("my-dialog", {
  template: `<v-dialog :value="dialog" persistent><v-card><v-text-field v-model="form.title"></v-text-field></v-card><v-btn @click="$emit('on-update', form)">Save</v-btn></v-dialog>`,
  props: {
    dialog: {},
    prop_item: {}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        title: null
      }
    };
  },
  watch: {
    dialog(value) {
      if (value) {
        Object.keys(this.prop_item).forEach((key) => {
          this.$set(this.form, key, this.prop_item[key]);
        });
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      edit_item: {},
      items: {
        id: 1,
        title: "Root",
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            parentId: 1,
            title: "Chapter 1",
            children: [
              { id: 3, parentId: 2, title: "Sub-chapter 1.1" },
              { id: 4, parentId: 2, title: "Sub-chapter 1.2" }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            parentId: 1,
            title: "Chapter 2",
            children: [
              { id: 6, parentId: 5, title: "Sub-chapter 2.1" },
              { id: 7, parentId: 5, title: "Sub-chapter 2.2" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showDialog(payload) {
      this.edit_item = payload;
      this.dialog = true;
    },

    onUpdate(form) {
      Object.keys(form).forEach((key) => {
        this.$set(this.edit_item, key, form[key]);
      });

      this.dialog = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. Now I got why you asked. Actually, in this case, I am updating only the title but at other places, I have more properties, like the title and description, and this dialog is common, so to re-use the logic, I have to send the object.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it still passes an object.

Comment: Thanks. For this approach, I am not sure because it seems very expensive to emit events one by one for each property. As this can be problematic if more than 10 properties.